ZX calculus representation of an HS gate
I have a circuit connected with HS gates that cyclically permutes the three Pauli operators under conjugation. I want to know what would be the best way to intuitively understand how HS is applied to a circuit. If I convert HS into ZX calculus representation, would it be a S gate (green spider with a phase pi/2) followed by an H gate or vice versa?

If the input edge is on the left and the output edge is on the right then the gates would go in circuit order (S then H) instead of algebra order.

Thanks for the answer! Wanted to check if it's just convention for gates or is there a particular reason behind it? Like would this hold true for if we had variable angle rotations like Rz(θ1)Rx(θ2) in a circuit where input is on the left and output on the right, would this go in the same order as well i.e Rx(θ2) first and then Rz(θ1)?
